# Magento 2: unable to override form.phtml of review

Tags: magento2, review

I need to override the form.phtml in order to add a custom field, but I don't know why but it is not working.

Here is what I did:

**/namespace/modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="review_product_form_component"/>
    <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews_tab" as="reviews" template="RLTSquare_ProductReviewImages::review.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="review_form" template="RLTSquare_ProductReviewImages::form.phtml" as="review_form">
                    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and then my form.phtml in: /namespace/modulename/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

I'm using [this](https://marketplace.magento.com/rltsquare-product-review-images.html) module. Everything works, except the form.phtml.

...Just so you know, here was the original `catalog_product_view.xml`.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="RLTSquare_ProductReviewImages::rltsquare_productreviewimages.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Please, help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. > app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.review.form">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::review/form.phtml</argument>
           </action>
       </referenceBlock>
   </body>
   ```
2. > app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/review/form.phtml

   ```
   <!-- The new form content here ... -->
   ```
3. > flush cache

   ```
   php bin/magento c:f
   ```

Comment: Uhm , are you sure? Not at the office yet , but the path of the form.phtml is not in templates/review, but only in templates. I mean, that's how I remember it :). Anyway, I'll try it

Comment: Tested. It is not working

Comment: With this, you rewrite the review form of product view page, I tested it and it works well, look your module maybe you have another problem, or try To create a new module just for testing. Good luck.

Comment: Actually I'm not using my module, I'm using this module https://marketplace.magento.com/rltsquare-product-review-images.html
Would you mind installing it and try it? Everything seems to work, but this module does not override the form.phtml. That's the only problem

Comment: I created another plugin from the scratch. I don't know where did you test that. I don't know on what version you tested it, but it is not working. At least on Magento 2.3.3

Comment: Ok, I figured that the ONLY way to solve the issue, was to put the custom form.phtml in app//design/frontend/theme/themename/Magento_Review/templates/form.phtml
How can it be possible? Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can override from your custom module. create layout file on below path,

> app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.tab" as="reviews" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" group="detailed_info" ifconfig="catalog/review/active">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form" ifconfig="catalog/review/active">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_CustomModule::form.phtml</argument>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And create form.phtml in below path

> app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
<!-- The new form content here ... -->
```

Clear the cache and check. Hope it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this module https://marketplace.magento.com/rltsquare-product-review-images.html then you need to modify the layout file like below :-

> app\code\RLTSquare\ProductReviewImages\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="RLTSquare_ProductReviewImages::rltsquare_productreviewimages.css"/>
    </head>
    <referenceBlock name="product.review.form">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">RLTSquare_ProductReviewImages::form.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```